# Why do you close the app when I change the page?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have two List <>.

```
List<Musei> ListMusei;
List<Regioni> reg;
```

the object "Musei" has the property "Paese", while the object "Regioni" has the property "NomeProvincia".
The List "reg" is inserted in a ListView, and when pressed on an item, this method is invoked:

```
private void Listviewcitt_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var result = ((Regioni)e.ClickedItem).NomeProvincia.ToString();
    var filtro = ListMusei.Where(x => x.Paese.Equals(result));
    try
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageAroundMe), filtro);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

application where I always closes. I thought there was some problem in the "AroundMe", and then paste the code here:
In Page AroundMe I do this:

```
 List<Musei> ListMusei;

protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ListMusei = (List<Musei>) e.Parameter;
    List<Pushpin> push = new List<Pushpin>();

    foreach (Musei SingoloMuseo in ListMusei)
    {
        Pushpin Pushpin pushpin1 = new ();
        GeoPoint posizioneP;
        try
        {
            MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync (SingoloMuseo.Indirizzo, null);
            posizioneP result.Locations.FirstOrDefault = ().Point;
            pushpin1.Name = SingoloMuseo.NomeMuseo;
            pushpin1.Location = posizioneP;
            push.Add (pushpin1);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             continue;
        }
}
```

Where is the problem? I can not even figure out where I will close

Comment: you are missing a closing `}` in your `foreach` loop by the way.. does this code actually compile.. have you also used the debugger to actually step through the code.. ? if so please tell us the line where the error is happening.. what is this `Pushpin Pushpin pushpin1 = new ();` doesn't even look like code that would compile

Comment: It seems that the app crashes when in Page AroundMe run this code in the method OnNavigatedTo:
 `ListMusei = (List <Museui>) e.Parameter;`

Comment: what does the error message tell you..? we are not mind readers btw

Comment: A few suggestions:  1. Don't swallow exceptions (`catch(Exception e) {}`) - they hide problems and make debugging much more difficult.  Either do something (log it) or let it bubble up.  2. Don't blindly cast unless you're _absolutely certain_ that it will succeed.  Check the type of `e.Parameter` _before_ casting.

Comment: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App1.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parameter like

```
 Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageAroundMe), filtro.ToList());
```

The invalid cast exception occurs because you are trying to cast IEnumerable type to List.